# Configure the Standard Release Process to Add the CAP File

Tags: maven, release, javacard

I am working on a custom Maven archetype to support development of Java Card applets.

I got things working largely already. But, I'm still failing to configure the release process.
The standard is, that Maven creates a JAR from the ./target/classes folder. That is great, but I would like it to add also the converted CAP to this release - exactly like the APK is added to your release if you use [maven-android-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/).
How can I configure this?